# mysql query for between operator with range

Tags: mysql

i have sample records ranking table

```
   SNO      NAME            TYPE    RANK1-RANK2      DATE    
2   sd sdf ds   Weekly  4    - 8    20-Sep-2011 19:23:02          
3   asd asd     Weekly  1    - 6    21-Sep-2011 19:23:02          
4   sdsdsfsd    Weekly  1    - 1000 22-Sep-2011 19:23:02
```

in the above example one records i have 20 sept 2011 i have ranks 1 - 8 , from form i used to select rank1 and rank2 , that rank1 and rank2 should not be in this range if insert to be success, other wise it should not be insert. for that i need select sql query can u any one answer this select sql query..

test case  for SNO 2 record

chosen  from form

> ```
>                      rank1 - rank2 insert 
>                        1    -  3     true
>                        2    -  6     false
>                        5    -  7     false
>                        10   -  100   true
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question and try to specify exactly what is your problem. It is not clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query to see if there is a record that prevents you from inserting. If it returns 1, then the insert would be prohibited.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table
WHERE rank1 NOT BETWEEN MIN(incomingRank1, incomingRank2) - 1 
                    AND MAX(incomingRank1, incomingRank2) + 1
  AND rank2 NOT BETWEEN MIN(incomingRank1, incomingRank2) - 1 
                    AND MAX(incomingRank1, incomingRank2) + 1
  AND date = incomingDate
```

Comment: but in mysql min and max functions have only single parameter not double

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly;
when you get a value other than 0 from this query, you can insert the data.

```
select count(*) from table t 
where 
(t.rank1 not between 4 and 8)
and 
(t.rank2 not between 4 and 8)
and
t.date = '2011-09-20'
```

Comment: every case it is coming zero count

Comment: read the test case where the insert action should be execute